# JScrollPane with JFrame doesnt autoscroll to bottom when JTree nodes are beyond the JFrame's view

Tags: java, swing

I have a `JTree` thats within `JScrollPane` thats within a `JFrame`**, below is relevant JFrame class:**

```
import xyz.GuiHelper.DocumentTreeModel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.AdjustmentListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollBar;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.event.TreeExpansionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TreeExpansionListener;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;


public class XMLTreeView extends JFrame {

    //The JTree to display the XML
    private JTree xmlTree;
    /*Document & DefaultMutableTreeNode  are encapsulated in DocumentTreeModel*/
    private DocumentTreeModel documentTreeModel;

    private Dimension dimensionRecalculated = null;
    Dimension dimension = null;

    public XMLTreeView(DocumentTreeModel documentTreeModel, String jTreeGuiName) throws HeadlessException {
        super();
        this.documentTreeModel = documentTreeModel;
        //jframe related      
        setTitle(jTreeGuiName);

        dimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        if (dimension != null) {
            dimensionRecalculated = new Dimension();
            //set to half screen size width
            dimensionRecalculated.setSize(dimension.getWidth() / 2, dimension.getHeight());
            initialize(jTreeGuiName, dimensionRecalculated);
        }

    }

    //TODO: add input validation
    private void initialize(String jTreeGuiName, Dimension dimension) {

        xmlTree = new JTree();
        JScrollPane scrollPaneForTree =  new JScrollPane(xmlTree); 
      
          xmlTree.addTreeExpansionListener(new TreeExpansionListener() {
            @Override
            public void treeExpanded(TreeExpansionEvent event) {
             
                System.out.println("Tree expanded!");
                JScrollBar sb = scrollPaneForTree.getVerticalScrollBar();
                sb.setValue((int)xmlTree.getSize().getHeight());
                scrollPaneForTree.setVerticalScrollBar(sb);
                scrollPaneForTree.revalidate();
            }

            @Override
            public void treeCollapsed(TreeExpansionEvent event) {
               
                   System.out.println("Tree collapsed!");
                    JScrollBar sb = scrollPaneForTree.getVerticalScrollBar();
                  sb.setValue((int)xmlTree.getSize().getHeight());
                scrollPaneForTree.setVerticalScrollBar(sb);
                scrollPaneForTree.revalidate();
                  
            }
        } );
        scrollPaneForTree.setViewportView( xmlTree);
        xmlTree.setName(jTreeGuiName);
        xmlTree.setPreferredSize(dimension);

      
        
        getContentPane().add(scrollPaneForTree, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        ((DefaultTreeModel) xmlTree.getModel()).setRoot(documentTreeModel.getTreeNode());
        addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {
                //release all the resource
                xmlTree = null;
                documentTreeModel.setTreeNode(null);
            }
        });
        

        // Settings of Window
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize((int) dimension.getWidth(), (int) dimension.getHeight());
        setState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_VERT);
        //Jframe
        xmlTree.setPreferredSize(dimension);
        xmlTree.setSize((int) dimension.getWidth(), (int) dimension.getHeight());
        setResizable(true);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
        
    }

}
```

When I expand the JTree nodes after a while, there too many nodes inside the viewport, therefore naturally I would like JScrollPance scroll down/vertically so I can view the newly visible nodes at the bottom of the JTree. I would like to scroll up if the collapse of the nodes. Im able to detect `treeExpanded`  & `treeCollapsed`, however the JScrollPane does not scroll beyond the size of the screen.

**Based on Stack commuity input I attempted:**

```
   xmlTree = new JTree();
        JScrollPane scrollPaneForTree = new JScrollPane(xmlTree);        
        xmlTree.addTreeSelectionListener(new TreeSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
                
                DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) xmlTree.getLastSelectedPathComponent();

                /* if nothing is selected */                
                if (node == null) {
                    return;
                } else {
                    /* retrieve the node that was selected */   
                    System.out.println("Scrolling");
                    xmlTree.scrollPathToVisible(xmlTree.getSelectionPath());
                }
                
            }
        });
```

**I would like to scroll down as long as I expand the tree & again scroll up when tree is collapsed.**

Thanks

Comment: Try wrapping the code in the `treeExpanded()` event in a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`. The state of the JTree may not be fully updated when then event is generated so the size may not be accurate. Also, I think you should be the max value from the scrollbar itself, not the tree.

Comment: Don’t mess around with the scrollbars. Just call [`scrollPathToVisible`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html#scrollPathToVisible-javax.swing.tree.TreePath-) on the tree.

Comment: @Holger, I updated the code based on your recommendation, see edited post, but its not working.  Problem lasgt node/child expand beyond view/click range so you cant  really click it. I think I need a way to increase JFrame size, so in a maximized window, the scroll wil lbe forced to scroll down. Algorithm might be if JTree expanded and last or latest node is outside of viewport increase JFrame by Y pixels, else if JTree collaspsed and last or lastest node is  viewport decrease JFrame by Y pixels.  In all othercases do nothing. I will try this later & post.